# Free tool for DB converting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I am looking for free tool (or some simple way) to convert SQL Server to SQLite. I need to convert just tables definitions with relations without data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DBSync for SQLite & MSSQL. Free version allow to convert DB without data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any automated tool to do that, but the difference between [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [SQLite `CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) is minor.  The main incompatibilities are:

- There is no `IDENTITY`.  The closest thing is `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.
- Foreign key enforcement is off by default (for backwards compatibility reasons).  There's a [pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) to turn it on.
- `CLUSTERED` is not supported.
- Tables do not have owners.

Most importantly, the [type system is different](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  In SQL Server terms, *every* column (except `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`) is a `sql_variant`.  The declaration is just the *preferred* type of the column, not a restriction.

The [SQL server data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) map to SQLite type affinities as follows:

- bigint, int, smallint, tinyint → INTEGER
- float, real → REAL
- char, nchar, ntext, nvarchar, text, varchar → TEXT

Any type name that SQLite doesn't recognize has NUMERIC affinity.  This works fine for `money` and `numeric`, but you'll probably want to rename `image` and `(var)binary` to `BLOB`.

Comment: yes, difference is minor. But when I have a lot of tables: do it manually - waste a lot of time.

Comment: It's just a matter of search & replace in your SQL scripts.